# setState triggers only certain functions

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the main.dart of a simple quiz app I was practicing on. From what I have learnt so far, when we call `setState()` it calls the build method and redraws the widgets.

So in this particular snippet of code, I tried experimenting with it. Both the first expanded widget (Question text) and the last row widget (scorekeeper) need to be redrawn since they are changing with every interaction.

It turns out that if I remove `quizBrain.nextQuestion();` out of `setstate()` the question label won't update. If do the same with `scoreKeeper.add(Icon(Icons.check,color: Colors.green,));`
it still works fine while adding new icons but won't clear them on calling reset since in both cases it has to change the content of the widget.

Why does this happen?

**Main.dart**

```
import \'package:flutter/material.dart\';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'quiz_brain.dart';

QuizBrain quizBrain = QuizBrain();

void main() => runApp(Quizzler());

class Quizzler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: QuizPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];

  void checkAnswer(bool userPickedAnswer) {
    bool correctAnswer = quizBrain.getCorrectAnswer();

    setState(() {
      if (quizBrain.isFinished() == true) {
        Alert(
                context: context,
                title: "Finished!",
                desc: "You have reached the end of Quiz")
            .show();

        quizBrain.reset();

        scoreKeeper = [];
      } else {
        if (userPickedAnswer == correctAnswer) {
          scoreKeeper.add(Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: Colors.green,
          ));
        } else {
          scoreKeeper.add(Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: Colors.red,
          ));
        }

        quizBrain.nextQuestion();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                quizBrain.getQuestionText(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                'True',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked true.
                checkAnswer(true);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                'False',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked false.
                checkAnswer(false);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: scoreKeeper,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Main.dart(question related)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'quiz_brain.dart';

QuizBrain quizBrain = QuizBrain();

void main() => runApp(Quizzler());

class Quizzler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: QuizPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];

  void checkAnswer(bool userPickedAnswer) {
    bool correctAnswer = quizBrain.getCorrectAnswer();

    if (quizBrain.isFinished() == true) {
      Alert(
              context: context,
              title: "Finished!",
              desc: "You have reached the end of Quiz")
          .show();

      quizBrain.reset();

      scoreKeeper = [];
    } else {
      if (userPickedAnswer == correctAnswer) {
        scoreKeeper.add(Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.green,
        ));
      } else {
        scoreKeeper.add(Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.red,
        ));
      }
      setState(() {
        quizBrain.nextQuestion();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                quizBrain.getQuestionText(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                'True',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked true.
                checkAnswer(true);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                'False',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked false.
                checkAnswer(false);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: scoreKeeper,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**quiz_brain.dart**

```
import 'question.dart';

class QuizBrain {
  int _questionNumber = 0;

  List<Question> _questionBank = [
    Question('Some cats are actually allergic to humans', true),
    Question('You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', false),
    Question('Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.', true),
    Question('A slug\'s blood is green.', true),
    Question('Buzz Aldrin\'s mother\'s maiden name was \"Moon\".', true),
    Question('It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.', true),
    Question(
        'No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.',
        false),
    Question(
        'In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are technically entitled to a state funeral, because the building is considered too sacred a place.',
        true),
    Question(
        'The loudest sound produced by any animal is 188 decibels. That animal is the African Elephant.',
        false),
    Question(
        'The total surface area of two human lungs is approximately 70 square metres.',
        true),
    Question('Google was originally called \"Backrub\".', true),
    Question(
        'Chocolate affects a dog\'s heart and nervous system; a few ounces are enough to kill a small dog.',
        true),
    Question(
        'In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.',
        true),
  ];

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber < _questionBank.length - 1) {
      _questionNumber++;
    }
  }

  String getQuestionText() {
    return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionText;
  }

  bool getCorrectAnswer() {
    return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionAnswer;
  }

  bool isFinished() {
    if (_questionNumber < _questionBank.length - 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      print("true");
      return true;
    }
  }

  void reset() {
    _questionNumber = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `Alert()` in your `setState()` isn't very useful, quite the opposite, it's using unnecessary resources. Whatever you want to have updated in the UI, put that in the `setState()` for instance, a counter that shows up on the screen. Since you're using a stateful widget and calling another class you might wanna use ChangeNotifier.

```
class QuizBrain with ChangeNotifierProvider{
  void reset() {
    _questionNumber = 0;
    notifiyListeners();

  }
}
```

as to 'Why does this happen?', I'm not sure about this but the you're calling nextQuestion from another class, and the icons are added directly in the same class you're calling it. But it shouldn't work. Are you fully reloading your app after changing anything that updates state? A hot reload won't suffice.